# How to populate nodes with imagefield programmatically?

Tags: 7, media

I'm trying to do a mass import of images to drupal nodes in D7 and ended up with lots of funny entries in the table {files_managed}.

This is the code I use:

```
  chdir('/path/to/drupal/root');
  define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

  $node = node_load(123);

  $dir = '/path/to/files';
  if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      $file_ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      switch ($file_ext) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'gif':
        case 'JPEG':
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'png':
          $name_explode = explode("_", $file);
          $image_location =  $dir .'/'. $file;

          $file_temp = file_get_contents($image_location);
          $file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, 'public://' . $file, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
          $node->field_ep_image = array(
            $node->language => array(
              0 => array(
              'fid' => $file_temp->fid,
              'filename' => $file_temp->filename,
              'filemime' => $file_temp->filemime,
              'uid' => 1,
              'uri' => $file_temp->uri,
              'status' => 1
              )
            )
          );
        break;
      }

    }

    closedir($handle);
  }
```

What is the correct way to populate an imagefield programmatically in D7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to store the fid on the node, the rest of the file data is stored in the files table.

So

```
$node->field_ep_image = array(
   $node->language => array(
     0 => array(
       'fid' => $file_temp->fid,
     )
   )
 );
```

should be fine.

You could also use the entity API module, which simplifies this for you:

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$node_wrapper->field_ep_image = $file_temp->fid;
```

If you are getting funny values you might want to check your file handling, are the files save in the files table as expected?

Comment: Hey googletorp, that's very good pointers there, especially for the new entity API. Didn't know I can do it like that.  As for the files table, to be precise, did you mean 'files_managed' table?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the exact answer to your question, but you could check how other modules do it. Devel Generate for instance (part of [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)) can populate image fields. Check out devel_generate_fields() in devel_generate.fields.inc and image_devel_generate() in image.devel_generate.inc.

Hope that helps.